# Upload Confusion -> Uploading file and saving image_path to db

Tags: forms, codeigniter, file-upload

I am a bit confused as to the best way to attach this issue - I have a form that I add to the database but now I would like to upload a image.

The image is ment to go to ./includes/uploads/ and the file name is ment to be inserted into image_path

**Controller**

```
class Addsale extends CI_Controller {

function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
}
function index() {
    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect('admin/home');
    }
    // Set Data
    $data['title'] = "Add Sale";
    $data['sales_pages'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesPages();
    $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();

    //Set File Settings
    $config['upload_path'] = './includes/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width'] = '1024';
    $config['max_height'] = '768';
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    //Set Validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('bedrooms', 'Bedrooms', 'trim|is_natural|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('bathrooms', 'Bathrooms', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('condition', 'Condition', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'trim|required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {

    $data = array(  
        'name' => $this->input->post('name', TRUE),
        'location' => $this->input->post('location', TRUE),
        'bedrooms' => $this->input->post('bedrooms', TRUE),
        'bathrooms' => $this->input->post('bathrooms', TRUE),
        'condition' => $this->input->post('condition', TRUE),
        'description' => $this->input->post('description', TRUE),
        'price' => $this->input->post('price', TRUE),
        'image_path' => $this->input->post('image', TRUE)
        );
        $data = array('image_path' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->sales_model->addSale($data);

        redirect('admin/addsale' , $data);

        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Page Saved');

    }else{
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/addsale', NULL, TRUE);
        $this->load->view('template', $data);
        }

}


}
```

**View**

```
<?php
//Setting form attributes
$formAddSale = array('id' => 'addSale', 'name' => 'addSale');
$saleName = array('id' => 'name', 'name' => 'name');
$saleLocation = array('id' => 'location', 'name' => 'location');
$saleBedrooms = array('id' => 'bedrooms','name' => 'bedrooms');
$saleBathrooms = array('id' => 'bathrooms','name' => 'bathrooms');
$saleCondition = array('id' => 'condition','name' => 'condition');
$saleImage = array('id' => 'image', 'name'=> 'image');
$saleDescription = array('id' => 'description','name' => 'description');
$salePrice = array('id' => 'price','name' => 'price');
?>

<section id = "validation"><?php print $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?></section>
<section id = "validation"><?php echo validation_errors();?></section>

<?php
echo form_open_multipart('admin/addsale/', $formAddSale);
echo form_fieldset();
echo form_label('Name:', 'name');
echo form_input($saleName);
echo form_label ('Location', 'location');
echo form_input($saleLocation);
echo form_label ('Bedrooms', 'bedrooms');
echo form_input($saleBedrooms);
echo form_label ('Bathrooms', 'bathrooms');
echo form_input($saleBathrooms);
echo form_label ('Condition', 'condition');
echo form_input($saleCondition);
echo form_label ('Price', 'price');
echo form_input($salePrice);
echo form_label('Image:', 'image');
echo form_upload($saleImage);
echo form_label ('Description', 'description');
echo form_textarea($saleDescription);
echo form_submit('submit','Submit');
echo form_fieldset_close();
echo form_close();
?>
```

**Model**

```
class Sales_model extends CI_Model
  {

function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
}

function getSalesPages() {

        $query = $this->db->get('sales');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) return $query->result();

    }

function addSale($data) {

$this->db->insert('sales', $data);
return;
}   

function updateSale($id, $data) {

    $this ->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('sales', $data);
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have this going and this was my final code:

```
    if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) { 

//Set File Settings 
$config['upload_path'] = './includes/uploads/'; 
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png'; 
$config['max_size'] = '100'; 
$config['max_width'] = '1024'; 
$config['max_height'] = '768'; 

$this->load->library('upload', $config); 

$this->upload->do_upload();
$file_info = $this->upload->data();

$data = array(   
    'name' => $this->input->post('name', TRUE), 
    'location' => $this->input->post('location', TRUE), 
    'bedrooms' => $this->input->post('bedrooms', TRUE), 
    'bathrooms' => $this->input->post('bathrooms', TRUE), 
    'condition' => $this->input->post('condition', TRUE), 
    'description' => $this->input->post('description', TRUE), 
    'price' => $this->input->post('price', TRUE), 
    'image' => $file_info['full_path'] 
    ); 
$this->sales_model->addSale($data); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you never actually called the do_upload method in your controller. try:

```
function index() {
if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
    redirect('admin/home');
}
// Set Data
$data['title'] = "Add Sale";
$data['sales_pages'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesPages();
$data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();

//Set File Settings
$config['upload_path'] = './includes/uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '100';
$config['max_width'] = '1024';
$config['max_height'] = '768';
$this->upload->initialize($config);

//Set Validation
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('bedrooms', 'Bedrooms', 'trim|is_natural|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('bathrooms', 'Bathrooms', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('condition', 'Condition', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'trim|required');

if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {

$data = array(  
    'name' => $this->input->post('name', TRUE),
    'location' => $this->input->post('location', TRUE),
    'bedrooms' => $this->input->post('bedrooms', TRUE),
    'bathrooms' => $this->input->post('bathrooms', TRUE),
    'condition' => $this->input->post('condition', TRUE),
    'description' => $this->input->post('description', TRUE),
    'price' => $this->input->post('price', TRUE),
    'image_path' => $this->input->post('image', TRUE)
    );

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        /// Upload Failed
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        // Print $error to user
    }
    else
    {
        // Upload Succeeded add the path to the data array
        $uploaded_file = $this->upload->data();
        $data['image_path'] = $uploaded_file['full_path'];
    }

    $this->sales_model->addSale($data);

    redirect('admin/addsale' , $data);

    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Page Saved');

}else{
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/addsale', NULL, TRUE);
    $this->load->view('template', $data);
    }
```

}

I haven't tested this code, but I pulled the do_upload block from the documentation so it should work.

Comment: Thanks Lee, This did not work due to the do_upload being a function and I am trying to do it within the main index function.

Comment: Hi Jess, the do_upload() method is part of the upload class, not your controller, it should work?